# How to detect or ignore hardware/external keyboard?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

How to detect or ignore if an external/hardware keyboard is set up?
I tried googling it, there isn't an easy way I could find.

Comment: detection/ ignorance of hardware keyboard will be OS not by the application

Comment: I have used pickers inside text fields, and i also move the screen when selecting a text field; but with a bluetooth keyboard set up to the iphone or ipad, it doesn't show the virtual keyboard